# Continuous function which has uncountable intersections with each parallel line to $y=x$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Does there exist a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ for which the following holds?
$$\forall k\in\mathbb{R}, 0<k<1 \: :\:\mathscr{S}_k= \{x\in[0,1]\mid f(x)=x+k\}\: \text{is an uncountable set}$$

Comment: For sure. Consider $f(x)=1.$

Comment: I don't see what need is there, other than to make a mistake, for all those $k$, $\alpha$ (?) and $\beta$ (??). The condition you've written is by all means just $$ \forall y\in (0,2),\ f^{-1}(y)\text{ is uncountable}$$

Comment: See my essays [Part 1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160395/smallest-positive-zero-of-weierstrass-nowhere-differentiable-function) and [Part 2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160184/level-sets-of-a-weierstrass-nowhere-differentiable-function), and the google search ["typical continuous function" + "level set"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22typical+continuous+function%22+%22level+set%22) for more than you proabably wanted to know exists.